# Are all Vsync options equal?

Tags: graphics-card

I've noticed there are a handful of ways to apply v-sync to a game:

- In-game option
- Catalyst Control Center
- D3DOverrider
- RadeonPro
- Windows 7 Desktop Window Manager (via DWM.exe when gaming in Windowed-Fullscreen mode)

What are the functional/applicable differences between methods? I'm trying to determine which method might be preferable over another, or when you might want to use one method over another.

Comment: How, in the name of all that is holy to gaming, is a question about correctly using gaming hardware and game video settings being voted as **off topic**?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie [I was wondering the same thing.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5669/is-a-question-about-a-graphics-cards-drivers-like-this-on-topic-wont-be-close)

Answer (score 2):

I've always used the in game options if available, then the CCC, then a 3rd party program like [www.radeonpro.info](http://www.radeonpro.info/) if necessary.

My reasoning has been this:

For games that don't support anti-aliasing in game, you can force it through the CCC. However, this method is less efficient than if the game supported anti-aliasing natively.

I've always applied this same logic to vSync.

Comment: Unlike AA I'm not sure if it really matters nearly as much *how* you impliment V sync though, so I doubt CCC Vsync is much/any worse than in game. Could be wrong though, I've just never noticed a difference.

Comment: @BenBrocka It's not how the vsync is implemented (there's only one implementation), it's how the game is/isn't programmed to mitigate the undesirable side-effects of vsync. If you use an external vsync, the game may not even *know* it's doing vsync and can't compensate; so built-in is always preferable, though won't always be better, if that makes sense?

Comment: for more info regarding present, cpu blocking etc etc: ( http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14639/non-blocking-vsync-in-direct3d )