# What is V-Sync and when should I enable it?

Tags: terminology, graphics-card, monitor

Most modern 3D games have a graphics option "V-Sync". It's usually an on/off setting. I'd like to *understand* settings I tweak with, and this one kind of eludes me.

**What does "V-Sync" mean, and when should I turn it on?**

---

I've tried a few things to answer my own question:

- [Search](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=v-sync+is%3Aq) arqade. There's a more [in-depth question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/111804/11084) about which way to go about enabling it, [another specific question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/182033/11084) about why limiting FPS to screen refresh rate won't prevent tearing, as well as several other game- or hardware-specific ones, but no real question or answer that explains what it is or when to use it at all.
- Use [Google search](https://www.google.nl/search?q=what+is+v-sync), which leads to a decent yet very [summary forum post on tomshardware](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/124553-13-what-vsync). It does explain to some degree *what* it is, but not in very much detail nor anything about *when* you'd turn it on.
- A [sub-entry on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing#V-sync), which is (a) rather short and (b) obviously encyclopedic instead of aimed at a gamer deciding whether to use this option.

Finally I've tried messing with the setting in various games, mainly when I saw and googled about the "tearing" of images I had in some games, but a gamer-oriented explanation of the what and when still eludes me...

As a gamer to a gamer: please tell me what the option is and give me a rule of thumb of when I should (and should *not*) consider turning it on/off?